# AppPermissionRequests (ACS) overwrite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app-permissions, acs

I couldn't find any direct answer online. Does anyone know, if using legacy `/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` on existing app (addin), the existing permissions will be overwritten, or appended? I found somewhere, that only way to remove previously granted permissions, is to remove and re-add permission again. This question applies to SharePoint Online specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your questions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#managing-and-troubleshooting-add-in-permissions?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698

[image]